# If else statement , global name not defined

Tags: python, if-statement, global-variables

```
def vel(y,umax,r,Rmax):
     vel_p=umax*(1-(r/Rmax)**2)

     if r<50:
        r=50-y
     else:
        r=y-50
     return 'the value of velocity in cell is %r,%r,%r,%r'%(umax,r,Rmax,vel_p)


def main ():

     y=(input('enter y'))   
     a=(input('enter the umax'))
     #b=(input('enter the r'))
     b=(r)
     c=(input('enter the Rmax'))
     print(vel(a,c,b,y))

main()
```

i do not understand where i should put r it gives me an error global variable r not defined

Comment: Well, why did you comment out the line that inputs the "r" and replace it with a reference to a non-existent variable?

Comment: You also do not need parenthesis around the `input`. This looks like it produces a `tuple` but it does not (missing the comma `,`) and can be confusing.

Comment: because i need to get the value of r from y , if i do not put that in comments it is taking my value of r and will not calculate from the if r statement

Comment: Also notice that `input()` will return a string. If you want to do calculations with the values, you have to convert to int or float. Also you should keep your variable names consistent. Your function `vel()` expects y, umax, r, Rmax in this order, yet you call it with a (which holds your value for umax), c (which holds Rmax), b (which should probably hold the value for r) and y.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, try to use "good" (=readable) variable names since this helps to reduce confusion.

The conversion from string to float should be made robust against non-numerical input with `try`...`except`, so I put that in a separate function.

Usually you don't want a function to return a string with all your calculated values inserted, but the "raw" values. The printing of those values should normally be done somewhere else.

In the comments you mention you "need to get the value of r from y, if i do not put that in comments it is taking my value of r and will not calculate from the if r statement", but your function `vel()` uses r to calculate vel_p in the very first line. The variable r is an argument to the function, so it has to come from somewhere. Either you let the user input it like all the other values, or you have to define it somewhere else. If you do that globally, have a look at Vipin Chaudharys answer.

My suggestion, if you want the user to input r:

```
def vel(y, u_max, r, r_max):
    # You use the value of r here already!
    vel_p=u_max*(1-(r/r_max)**2)

    # Here you change r, if r is less than 50.
    # You are using r again, before assigning a new value!
    if r<50:
        r=50-y
    else:
        r=y-50

    # I use the preferred .format() function with explicit field names
    # \ is used to do a line-break for readability
    return 'The value of velocity in cell is umax: {value_u_max}, \
r: {value_r}, Rmax: {value_r_max}, vel_p: {value_vel_p}.'.format(
    value_u_max=u_max, value_r=r,value_r_max=r_max, value_vel_p=vel_p)

# Helper function to sanitize user input    
def numberinput(text='? '):
    while True:
        try:
            number=float(input(text))
            # return breaks the loop
            return number
        except ValueError:
            print('Input error. Please enter a number!')


def main():
    y=numberinput('Enter y: ')
    u_max=numberinput('Enter the umax: ')
    r=numberinput('Enter the r: ')
    r_max=numberinput('Enter the Rmax: ')
    print(vel(y, u_max, r, r_max))

main()
```

Notice, that the input value of r is used to do the calculation. Then it is changed depending on y, and the new value gets printed.

Comment: Hi , can you please tell me if i need to print just the value of my vel that what syntax or command i should give ?? now it is returning the whole arguments but i need just the velocity.

Comment: If you only want to print the value of `vel`, change the `return` statement of your function: `return 'The value of velocity in cell is {value_vel_p}.'.format(value_vel_p=vel_p)`

Answer (score -1):

In your **main** method , you assigned `b = (r)` whereas you never specified what is r , so if you have variable `r` in your global scope then the first line in the main method should be

```
def main():
   global r
   # Now you can use your r
```

by doing so , you called your variable `r` in your method.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: then why a -1 for my answer , please mark it correct if it worked for you :\

Comment: i didn't marked any , in fact i cannot , i am trying to increase but not possible from my side sir